# Converting object into array in python

Tags: python

I need to convert a PHP/JSON "object" (Python dict) into an array for filler words and show filler words with no count that will not be shown. How can I do this?

This is written as an object:

```
filler_word = {'um': 9, 'uh': 4, 'hmm': 0, 'mhm': 0, 'uh huh': 0}
```

This is how I want to have it into an array:

```
filler_word = ['um': 9, 'uh': 4, 'hmm': 0, 'mhm': 0, 'uh huh': 0]
```

This is how I want to show those filler words with 0 count that will not be shown:

```
filler_word = ['um': 9, 'uh': 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are bringing PHP thinking to your Python coding.  The two are very different.  What you have in the first line is a dictionary, which is the equivalent of a PHP array, and is used like a PHP array.

Python lists do not have keys.  So, this is a list:

```
mylist = [ 9, 4, 0, 0 ]
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a ***dict comprehension***:

```
{key: value for key,value in filler_word.items() if value > 0 }

{'um': 9, 'uh': 4}
```